# Migrating from Cocoapods to Swift Package Manager but import module failed

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode11, swift-package-manager

recently I'm refactoring a project which uses Cocoapods to manage dependencies (a lot of dependencies...), since Xcode 11 integrated Swift Package Manager, I want to migrate progressively some dependencies to SPM staring from the framework `Alamofire`.

After I removed the Alamofire from the Podfile (delete and run `pod install`) and added it into SPM,

[image]

I got the error `No such module 'Alamofire'`.

[image]

I've already tried to clean build and removed derived data but none of them can fix it.
Did anyone have this problem too?

Comment: Did you add the package to target -> general-> "Frameworks, Libraries, and embedded content"?

Comment: @Lapieuvre Yes it is added in this section

Comment: @Sammy I just tried pod update and it doesn't work either :( And the platform is :ios, '10.0'

Comment: @Sammy I did but it still doesn't work...

Comment: @Sammy But I want to remove it from Cocoapods and use it by Swift Package Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few days searching, I found out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57312755/863020.

Seems that SPM could be only used for `Debug` and `Release` configurations, if we want to use it with more configurations then we should write a pre-action. And it is also a known issue on Xcode so I would not use SPM for now :(

**UPDATED on dec. 12**

So I come back to my question after the new release of Xcode 11.3, it fixed this issue and now I can build the project with custom build configuration :)