# Swift package showing error as No such module for added dependency

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have successfully added another swift package dependencies to my main Swift Package project.

[image: Swift Package Dependencies inside Swift package project]

However, when I import dependencies in my swift files, it gives error.

AppLogger is a swift package which has successfully added dependencies but not able to import it.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165778/getting-no-such-module-error-when-importing-a-swift-package-manager-dependency

Comment: Ali linked to what I was going to answer. I think that’s the issue

Comment: I am quite not sure what should I add in my current SPM to compile dependencies correctly from above link.

Answer (score 0):

Module got imported successfully after I added `dependencies` in Package's targets as follows:

```
dependencies: [
    .product(
        name: "CocoaLumberjackSwift",
        package: "CocoaLumberjack"
    ),
    "CoreInfrastructure"
]
```